# Update/refresh a component using another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

I'm sorry for this question but I'm new to react and trying to find best practice on how to update another class component from another class component.

For example I have AddItem.js and ViewItem.js but has the same route. I'm updating ViewItem.js ListGroup by re-rending(componentDidMount()). How can I do this with AddItem.js button onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a new state property in the parent and pass that as props to AddItem and ViewItem and use that prop as a state for these two components and in your button click event you can change the state and react renders the component automatically on state change.

See this simple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-umwgbl)

Comment: I see, then I think I'm doing it wrong. Should I also place all my function/https request inside my App.js then just pass data as prop to ViewItem.js?

Comment: It depends on the file/folder structure you're trying to maintain across your app. Although it doesn't matter if you're working on a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

If ViewItem and AddItem are siblings, then you can call methods of each other using ref of another component [use ref doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

OR 
you can also wrap both with parent component and use parent state for both the child.

If Viewitem and Additem are child-parent or vice versa then you can use pass props and change state based on the change in props.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by creating a parent class (for example Home.js) on top of AddItem.js and ViewItem.js and pass data as props on click to the child component.

In case you if you are using React and Redux it becomes relatively simple on click of a button you can call method in your action.js which will dispatch an action with payload data to the reducer, which can we used by adding mapStatetoProps() in  ViewItem.js and AddItem.js, so once you receive the data in your props variables it will reload/refresh that particular component.